# Accessing struct members after allocating

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

my first time here. Tried to find a solution through searching, but i still cant see my problem here:

Struct

```
typedef struct
{
    float** image_data;  
    int m;             
     int n;             
} image;
```

shorted main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int m, n, c, iters;
    image u;
    unsigned char *image_chars;
    char *input_jpeg_filename, *output_jpeg_filename;

    /*funtion importing jpeg sets chars and hight/width (works)*/ 
    import_JPEG_file(input_jpeg_filename, &image_chars, &m, &n, &c);

    allocate_image (&u, m, n);
    printf"m og n (in main function): %i %i\n", u->m, u->n);

    return 0;
}
```

allocating function

```
void allocate_image(image *u, int m, int n)
{
    u = malloc(sizeof(struct image));

    u->m=m;
    u->n=n;

    int i;
    u->image_data=(float**)malloc(m*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        u->image_data[i]=(float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    }

    printf("m og n: %i %i\n", u->m, u->n);
}
```

Should mention its a part of school assignment, but I was told there was no harm in asking rudimentary questions here. I'm also limited to C89.

So as an experienced coder may already see, it doesn't allocate properly. the m and n values are printed correctly inside the allocate function, but I'm not allowed to use u->m for some reason outside. I have a feeling I messed up some pointers vs. addresses, but I can't find it..

As for remaking all the code, I would like to try and keep the variables inside main (no globals).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `u = malloc(sizeof(struct image));` only changes the function argument. It is not passed back to caller.

Comment: outside the function - you should reference the members of 'image' like ...  printf("m og n: %i %i\n", u.m, u.n); - as u is not a pointer to image.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you can tell why this function doesn't work:

```
void negate(int x)
{
    x = -x;
}
```

It doesn't work because parameters in C are "passed by value". As a result, changes to formal parameter `x` can't affect the corresponding actual variable.

In your case,

```
void allocate_image(image *u, int m, int n)
{
    u = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
    ...
```

has the same problem. To modify a **image** in a function, you should pass a **pointer to image**; to modify a **pointer to image** in a function, you should pass a **pointer to pointer to image**.

Here is the refined allocating function:

```
void allocate_image(image **u, int m, int n)
{
    *u = malloc(sizeof (struct image));

    (*u)->m = m;
    (*u)->n = n;

    size_t i;
    (*u)->image_data = malloc(m * sizeof (float *));
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        (*u)->image_data[i] = malloc(n * sizeof (float));
    }

    printf("m og n: %i %i\n", (*u)->m, (*u)->n);
}
```

Note that operator `*`(unary) has lower procedure than operator `->`, so the parentheses cannot be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, inside your function, you're trying to allocate memory for `u` whereas, you had passed the address of a statically-allocated variable. So, inside your function, you're writing into a temporary memory location, will will not be existing when you try to access back the passed argument in the caller.

Thereby, the memory instance of `u` inside the function is local to the function and the changes made will disappear when the function exits. Remove the memory allocation, you don't need that.

Comment: to put in other words, either you have to return the pointer allocated for `u` or pass `u` with double indirection, `void allocate_image(image **u, int m, int n)`, then change all references of `u` to `*u` (location pointed by u). Of course you need to pass `&u` in your caller function.